# Validación de una lista desplegable en Laravel

Tags: laravel, validación, relaciones

tengo una vista en Laravel 8 que gestiona datos de Vendedores, tiene un campo desplegable cuyo contenido es una lista de usuarios, lo que necesito hacer es validar que cada Vendedor, tenga asociado un usuario, es decir que exista una relación 1 a 1 entre vendedores y usuarios. Ahora bien, lo que no se es como hacer para validar que un usuario no esté asignado a un vendedor al momento de grabar los datos del vendedor. Tengo en funcionamiento las demás validaciones del formulario, pero no logro enganchar como hacer la mencionada validación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen les muestro este desplegable que se carga con los datos de los usuarios, y al momento de grabar, debería verificar que el usuario seleccionado, no esté asociado a un vendedor, de otra forma, no estaría respetando la relación 1 a 1 establecida para usuarios y vendedores.

Las demás validaciones las estoy haciendo en el Controller de Vendedores:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 */
private function validarCampos(Request $request): void
{
    $request->validate([
        'id_usuario' => 'required',
        'nombre' => 'required|max:100',
        'telCelular' => 'required',
        'ctaEmail' => 'required',
        'avatar'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg,webp|max:2048'
    ],
    [
        'id_usuario.required'=>'Debe seleccionar un Usuario de la Lista de Usuarios',
        'nombre.required'=>'Debe ingresar un Nombre',
        'nombre.max'=>'Cantidad máxima de caracteres permitidos = 100',
        'telCelular.required'=>'Debe ingresar un número de teléfono celular',
        'ctaEmail.required'=>'Debe ingresar una cuenta de correo electrónico válida',
        'avatar.mimes'=>'Debe seleccionar un archivo de imágen',
        'avatar.max'=>'El archivo de imagen pesa mas de 2Mb'
    ]);
}
```

y este el procedimiento para validar dentro del Controller:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 */
private function validarCampos(Request $request): void
{
    $request->validate([
        'id_usuario' => 'required',
        'nombre' => 'required|max:100',
        'telCelular' => 'required',
        'ctaEmail' => 'required',
        'avatar'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg,webp|max:2048'
    ],
    [
        'id_usuario.required'=>'Debe seleccionar un Usuario de la Lista de Usuarios',
        'nombre.required'=>'Debe ingresar un Nombre',
        'nombre.max'=>'Cantidad máxima de caracteres permitidos = 100',
        'telCelular.required'=>'Debe ingresar un número de teléfono celular',
        'ctaEmail.required'=>'Debe ingresar una cuenta de correo electrónico válida',
        'avatar.mimes'=>'Debe seleccionar un archivo de imágen',
        'avatar.max'=>'El archivo de imagen pesa mas de 2Mb'
    ]);
}
```

Saludos y hasta otro contacto.

Comment: Ok, entiendo tu consejo, pero sería cargar la lista con los que no están asociados. Creo que podría ser útil. Puse la pregunta por si había alguna otra solución en Laravel y que se pudiera manejar dentro del procedimiento ValidarCampos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que se me ocurre, es usando la regla de validación [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in).

> El campo bajo validación debe incluirse en la lista de valores dada. Dado que esta regla a menudo requiere que implosione una matriz, el método
> `Rule::in` puede usarse para construir con fluidez la regla.

Entonces a esa regla deberías pasarle un array con las ids que están permitidas, o sea las de los Usuarios que aún no han sido asignados a un Vendedor. Para eso puedes [consultar la ausencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

Por ejemplo, si el modelo se llama `User` y la relación `vendedor`, la consulta sería:

```
$ids_permitidas = User::doesntHave('vendedor')->pluck('id');
```

Luego se lo pasas a la regla `in`;

```
$request->validate([
    'id_usuario' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in($ids_permitidas->toArray()),
    ],
    //...
],
[
    //...
]);
```

---

O al revés también, y quiza más eficiente, obteniendo las ids del modelo Vendedor, y usando la regla `notIn`.

```
$ids_no_permitidas = Vendedor::pluck('id_usuario');

//...

'id_usuario' => [
    'required',
    Rule::notIn($ids_no_permitidas->toArray()),
],
```

---

Aunque ahora que lo miro mejor, creo que la regla [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) sería la más indicada.

```
'id_usuario' => 'required|unique:tabla_vendedores,id_usuario',
```

Dejo las anteriores sólo como alternativas.

---

Otras referencias:
Query Builder [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values).
Collections [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray).

Answer (score 1):

En función de las respuestas que me brindaron, tomé en consideración la primer sugerencia de cargar el desplegable SOLO con los registros de Users que aún no estaban vinculados a ningún Vendedor, de esa manera pude resolver el problema que tenía, es decir, evitar que un user me quedara vinculado a mas de un vendedor, con lo cual se podía romper la relación uno a uno que existe entre users y vendedores. Y del segundo post, utilicé el concepto de seleccionar aquellos registros que no están dentro de la relación, es decir, aquellos users que aún no fueron asignados a algún vendedor. Para ello, realicé la implementación dentro del modelo Vendedor, tal como se muestra a continuación:

```
public function usrNoVinculados(){
    $usrs = DB::select('select * from users where id NOT IN(select usuario_id FROM vendedores)');
    return $usrs;
}
```

y luego, cuando necesito cargar la vista, lo utilizo desde el Controller de Vendedor de la siguiente manera:

```
    public function edit($id){
    $itVendedor = Vendedor::find($id);
    $usuarios = $itVendedor->usrNoVinculados();
    return view('/vendedores.editDtosVendedores',
    [
        'usuarios' => $usuarios,
        'vendedor'=> $itVendedor
    ]);
}
```

por último, se convoca esta vista desde:

```
Route::get('vendedores/{id}/edit', [VendedorController::class, 'edit'] )->name('vendedores.edit');
```

la línea $usuarios = $itVendedor->usrNoVinculados(); devolverá SOLO la lista de users que aún no están vinculados a ningún vendedor, siendo este el objetivo que perseguía sin romper la relación uno a uno entre users y vendedores.

Saludos y Gracias por los aportes que me sirvieron de soporte a esta implementación.

Comment: En estos casos considera marcar como aceptada aquella respuesta que te resolvió el problema, es la mejor forma de agradecer y de paso le dices a la comunidad sobre que aporte guiarse